# Start replication again from crashed MySQL master

Tags: mysql, replication, mariadb

I am messing around with MySQL replication trying to learn about it and have ran into a snag that I can't seem to find the solution to. I have a local instance of MySQL running as Master and a remote instance in AWS running as Slave. I had to restart my computer so the Master instance died and when I booted it back up again and ran `SHOW MASTER STATUS\G` it showed a new binlog filename and position which is probably fine and expected. However the Slave still shows the old binlog file name and position where it left off.

I figured just running `STOP SLAVE; START SLAVE;` would fix the issue but it resulted in an error: `Got fatal error 1236 from master when reading data from binary log: 'Client requested master to start replication from impossible position; the first event 'bin.000004' at 63938331, the last event read from 'bin.000004' at 4, the last byte read from 'bin.000004' at 4.'`

What would be the proper steps for recovering from this?
I don't have the replication setup to start writing to the slave on failure of Master because I don't need it. I am basically using the Slave as a read only copy to run reports off of.

I am hoping there is an easier way than taking a snapshot of the master and restoring it to the slave and basically starting from scratch.

**EDIT:**
This is just for development and learning at the moment. There really isn't any critical data in there but I would like to know how to handle situations like these for when I do deploy it to production.

**EDIT 2**

Relevant lines from Master config

```
server-id=1
log-bin=bin.log
log-bin-index=bin-log.index
max_binlog_size=100M
binlog_format=ROW
```

Relevant lines from Slave config

```
server-id = 2
replicate-do-db=asterisk
replicate-do-db=asteriskcdrdb
```

Comment: `log-bin=bin.log` -->  `log_bin=ON` and `log_bin_basename=bin.log`

Comment: @RickJames I am using MariaDB-10.4 and for some reason it says that ```log_bin_basename``` isn't a valid variable even though their documentation show it introduced in 10.1. Any ideas why?

Comment: _Note:_ the `-` versions are on the command line; the `_` versions are in `my.cnf`.  This particular setting is not quite parallel between the two places (unlike most settings).